# UITableView dynamic height cannot satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to use autolayout to dynamically determine the height of my table cells using this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

The problem is, I'm getting these weird automatic constraints that set the dimensions to the simulated metrics of my custom cell. I have done a lot of autolayout, and I thought the simulated metrics weren't supposed to affect the actual app at runtime. Did something change in the new SDK?

Anyway, here is the method I've been messing with...

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            static JMSocialFeedTableViewCell *sizingCell = nil;
            static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
            dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                    sizingCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
            });
           [self configureCell:sizingCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

           //[sizingCell.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:sizingCell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0 constant:self.tableView.frame.size.width]];

           [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
           [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

           //CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
           CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
           return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
    }
```

The commented out lines are different things I was trying. My simulated metrics are 300 x 389. The sizeThatFits method returns this size even though the table view is 320 wide. The systemLayoutSizeFittingSize returns 400 x 489 for whatever reason. In these cases, it is easy to see why I'm getting unsatisfiable constraints, as the height should be 409 (+1.0F for seperator maybe. I've been trying with and without that too).

I'm not setting any other constraints in code, but if I try adding the one I have commented in the code above I'm getting this weird constraint...

```
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1701ebf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x1705a310(300)]>"
```

I don't know why the number 300 keeps showing up. I thought simulated metrics were supposed to be gone once the view is laid out.

Sorry if my question isn't 100% clear. I guess I'm confused on a few points. Basically I'm trying to get autolayout to determine the proper height of my cell given that the cell's width should be equal to the width of the table view (which is 320 on the device I'm testing on).

Comment: what do you constraints look like in the cell?

Comment: height-wise I have 2 elements that are 44 tall each.  Then I have an image view that stretches to the left and right and has an aspect ratio of 1:1.  So the height is really based off the width of the cell.  Interface builder says the constraints are good - no warnings or errors.

Comment: can you share a screen shot of the interface builder layout? I can't quite picture that.

Comment: http://imgur.com/iuSdkVQ  So the height should be 89 + the width of the table view

Comment: Do you have constraints equaling 0 to the parent leading and trailing the image? that should force your width of your cell to be the width of the table   and give that image a height of 320 (assuming your table is the width of the screen) and ultimately give your cell a height of 408+the 1px you're adding.

Comment: It's always good practice to have the bottom constraint to parent be >= whatever constant you want...seems like 0 or 44 in your case.

Comment: I have those constraints... When I try to return the table width + 89.0f for the height I get that weird constraint setting the width to the simulated width.  I did what you said and made the bottom constraint >=.  I wish I could just get it to calculate the height correctly though.

Comment: What happens if you remove the simulated width?...I never use simulated metrics, so I'm unsure of their effect.